# DolphinScheduler how to add a worker server

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

I want to add a server as worker server
how many step I need to follow ?
thank you.
Which version of DolphinScheduler:
-[1.2.0]

Answer (score 0):

1、Create deployment user and hosts mapping, please refer 1.3 part of cluster deployment

2、Configure hosts mapping and ssh access and modify directory permissions. please refer 1.4 part of cluster deployment

3、copy the deployment directory from worker server that has already deployed

4、go to bin dir, then start worker server and logger server
./dolphinscheduler-daemon.sh start worker-server
./dolphinscheduler-daemon.sh start logger-server

ps:to 1.3, please referer doc: https://github.com/apache/incubator-dolphinscheduler-website/blob/master/docs/zh-cn/1.3.3/user_doc/expansion-reduction.md